# Script correction for count positive values in text file

Tags: perl, text-files

Some time ago, I ask for help to generate a Perl Script that counts values in a text file divide into parts.
This script says to me when a positive value is present in some lines of a text file, then when beginning another part of the text, say to me again the number of positive values.
For example, this is my text file:

```
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2   25 NKSP   0.1462     (9/9)   ---   
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2   66 NLTW   0.7837     (9/9)   +++   
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  116 NTTQ   0.7013     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  126 NGTH   0.7112     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  163 NCTY   0.7620     (9/9)   +++   
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  173 NIST   0.6556     (8/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  231 NITY   0.7442     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  273 NGTI   0.7109     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  322 NITQ   0.6116     (8/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  334 NITS   0.7296     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  361 NSSA   0.5388     (6/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  462 NPSG   0.4656     (5/9)   -     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  541 NSTK   0.5883     (8/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  590 NASS   0.5643     (6/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  603 NCTD   0.7117     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  646 NSSY   0.5467     (4/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  665 NVSS   0.7980     (9/9)   +++   
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  695 NNTI   0.4537     (5/9)   -     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  703 NFSI   0.5613     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  787 NFSQ   0.6209     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2 1060 NFTT   0.4540     (6/9)   -     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2 1084 NGTH   0.5408     (6/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2 1120 NNTV   0.5803     (6/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2 1144 NHTS   0.3828     (8/9)   -     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2 1149 NVSL   0.4879     (5/9)   -     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2 1159 NASV   0.5021     (3/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2 1180 NESL   0.5770     (7/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA   25 NKSP   0.1462     (9/9)   ---   
;ADK66841.1_NA   66 NLTW   0.7837     (9/9)   +++   
;ADK66841.1_NA  116 NTTQ   0.7013     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA  126 NGTH   0.7112     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA  163 NCTY   0.7620     (9/9)   +++   
;ADK66841.1_NA  173 NIST   0.6556     (8/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA  231 NITY   0.7442     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA  273 NGTI   0.7109     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA  322 NITQ   0.6116     (8/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA  334 NITS   0.7296     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA  361 NSSA   0.5388     (6/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA  462 NPSG   0.4656     (5/9)   -     
;ADK66841.1_NA  541 NSTK   0.5883     (8/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA  590 NASS   0.5643     (6/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA  603 NCTD   0.7117     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA  646 NSSY   0.5467     (4/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA  665 NVSS   0.7980     (9/9)   +++   
;ADK66841.1_NA  695 NNTI   0.4537     (5/9)   -     
;ADK66841.1_NA  703 NFSI   0.5613     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA  787 NFSQ   0.6209     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA 1060 NFTT   0.4540     (6/9)   -     
;ADK66841.1_NA 1084 NGTH   0.5408     (6/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA 1120 NNTV   0.5803     (6/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA 1144 NHTS   0.3828     (8/9)   -     
;ADK66841.1_NA 1149 NVSL   0.4879     (5/9)   -     
;ADK66841.1_NA 1159 NASV   0.5021     (3/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA 1180 NESL   0.5770     (7/9)   +
```

This file reports to me when a positive value is present: only 0.7 >= are positive values. The text file has two parts: one for *YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2* and the other for *ADK66841.1_NA*. When you count the numbers of positive values (7>=) in each part, there are 9 positive values for each part.
I have a lot of files like this with hundreds of parts, for this reason, I ask for an idea about one script in Perl to count these values.
This is the script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cnt = {};
while(my $line = <STDIN>) {
    if($. == 1) {
        next;
    }else {
        my @cols = split(m{\s+},$line);
        if(@cols == 6) {
            my $potential = $cols[3];
            my $id = $cols[0];
            $id =~ s{^\;}{};
            if(0.7 >= $potential) {
                $cnt->{$id}++;
            };
        };
    };
};

my @ids_found = sort { $a cmp $b } (keys %$cnt);

for my $id (@ids_found) {
    print "PART $id:\n";
    print "$cnt->{$id} (values 0.7 >=)\n";
};
```

This works fine, however, I noticed that there is an error in the output.
The output:

```
$ cat Test00.txt | perl File_for_count_values.pl 
PART ADK66841.1_NA:
18 (values 0.7 >=)
PART YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2:
18 (values 0.7 >=)
```

The output doesn´t look like just I want it, when counting values this script **plus the positive values of each part (9 + 9 = 18)**.
The output must be:

```
$ cat Test00.txt | perl File_for_count_values.pl 
PART ADK66841.1_NA:
9 (values 0.7 >=)
PART YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2:
9 (values 0.7 >=)
```

Any idea about what must change in the script to do that?

Any comment is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code counts the values which are **less than or equal to** 0.7.
If I change:

```
        if(0.7 >= $potential) {
```

to:

```
        if(0.7 <= $potential) {
```

then I get 9 for each part.  Output:

```
PART ADK66841.1_NA:
9 (values 0.7 >=)
PART YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2:
9 (values 0.7 >=)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please investigate the following re-worked perl script for usefulness.

NOTE: original code assumes a header based on an instruction `if($. == 1)` -- see [$.](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$.)

A few changes was implemented to improve readability of the script

- a variable `$threshold` defined at top of the script
- skip the header/first line with `next unless $. > 1` (next unless line counter more than one)
- split line not only on spaces but `;` as well to avoid substitute
- `$id`,`$potential` filled from `@cols` array in one instruction
- field numbers adjusted as first field before `;` will be empty
- [write](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/write) with [format](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlform) utilized for formatted output

NOTE: see [$~](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%7E) which defines current format for `write` output, utilized to close the table

This script utilizes `__DATA__` block with originally posted data for output demonstration purpose.

Alter the code with `while( <> )` instead `while( <DATA> )`, what would allow you accept input from `STDIN` or by specifying filename as an argument to the script (run as `./script.pl file.dat`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# vim: ai ts=4 sw=4

use strict;
use warnings;

my($id,$counter);
my $treshold = 0.7;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    next unless $. > 1;
    my @cols = split("[; ]+", $_);
    next unless @cols == 7;
    my($id,$potential) = @cols[1,4];
    $counter->{$id}++ if $potential >= $treshold;
}

my @sorted_ids = sort { $a cmp $b } keys %$counter;

for $id (@sorted_ids) {
    write;
}

$~ = "STDOUT_BOTTOM";
write;

exit 0;

format STDOUT_TOP =

Criteria:          potential >= @#.##
$treshold

+-----------------------------+-------+
| Part                        | Count |
+-----------------------------+-------+
.

format STDOUT =
| @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< | @>>>> |
$id,$counter->{$id}
.

format STDOUT_BOTTOM =
+-----------------------------+-------+

.

__DATA__
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2   25 NKSP   0.1462     (9/9)   ---   
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2   66 NLTW   0.7837     (9/9)   +++   
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  116 NTTQ   0.7013     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  126 NGTH   0.7112     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  163 NCTY   0.7620     (9/9)   +++   
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  173 NIST   0.6556     (8/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  231 NITY   0.7442     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  273 NGTI   0.7109     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  322 NITQ   0.6116     (8/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  334 NITS   0.7296     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  361 NSSA   0.5388     (6/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  462 NPSG   0.4656     (5/9)   -     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  541 NSTK   0.5883     (8/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  590 NASS   0.5643     (6/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  603 NCTD   0.7117     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  646 NSSY   0.5467     (4/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  665 NVSS   0.7980     (9/9)   +++   
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  695 NNTI   0.4537     (5/9)   -     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  703 NFSI   0.5613     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2  787 NFSQ   0.6209     (9/9)   ++    
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2 1060 NFTT   0.4540     (6/9)   -     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2 1084 NGTH   0.5408     (6/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2 1120 NNTV   0.5803     (6/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2 1144 NHTS   0.3828     (8/9)   -     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2 1149 NVSL   0.4879     (5/9)   -     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2 1159 NASV   0.5021     (3/9)   +     
;YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2 1180 NESL   0.5770     (7/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA   25 NKSP   0.1462     (9/9)   ---   
;ADK66841.1_NA   66 NLTW   0.7837     (9/9)   +++   
;ADK66841.1_NA  116 NTTQ   0.7013     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA  126 NGTH   0.7112     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA  163 NCTY   0.7620     (9/9)   +++   
;ADK66841.1_NA  173 NIST   0.6556     (8/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA  231 NITY   0.7442     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA  273 NGTI   0.7109     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA  322 NITQ   0.6116     (8/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA  334 NITS   0.7296     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA  361 NSSA   0.5388     (6/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA  462 NPSG   0.4656     (5/9)   -     
;ADK66841.1_NA  541 NSTK   0.5883     (8/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA  590 NASS   0.5643     (6/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA  603 NCTD   0.7117     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA  646 NSSY   0.5467     (4/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA  665 NVSS   0.7980     (9/9)   +++   
;ADK66841.1_NA  695 NNTI   0.4537     (5/9)   -     
;ADK66841.1_NA  703 NFSI   0.5613     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA  787 NFSQ   0.6209     (9/9)   ++    
;ADK66841.1_NA 1060 NFTT   0.4540     (6/9)   -     
;ADK66841.1_NA 1084 NGTH   0.5408     (6/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA 1120 NNTV   0.5803     (6/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA 1144 NHTS   0.3828     (8/9)   -     
;ADK66841.1_NA 1149 NVSL   0.4879     (5/9)   -     
;ADK66841.1_NA 1159 NASV   0.5021     (3/9)   +     
;ADK66841.1_NA 1180 NESL   0.5770     (7/9)   +
```

Output

```
Criteria:          potential >=  0.70

+-----------------------------+-------+
| Part                        | Count |
+-----------------------------+-------+
| ADK66841.1_NA               |     9 |
| YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp |     9 |
+-----------------------------+-------+
```

Note:

The file you refer me to on GitHub does not include leading `;` in data file. Due this reason count of number fields is less by one and causing not getting any result.

Please make following changes in perl script:

```
       next unless @cols == 7;
       my($id,$potential) = @cols[1,4];
```

to

```
       next unless @cols == 6;
       my($id,$potential) = @cols[0,3];
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for my LATE answers, I forget to comment about this script. First, thank you for taking your time to do this script. Second, I have one question about your script: Is it necessary to add the all _DATA_ at the end of the file.pl? I ask this because when I run the script with this: `perl file.pl datafile.txt` result with an empty box in the PART and COUNT output @PolarBear

Comment: This is my empty output: `Criteria:          potential >=  0.70

+-----------------------------+-------+
| Part                        | Count |
+-----------------------------+-------+
+-----------------------------+-------+`

Comment: Hello, you can delete block `__DATA__` and make repacement to `while( <> ) {` to be able read from `STDIN` or file given as an argument. I have tested it as `./script.pl data.dat` and the script produced same result as in my message.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the `__DATA__`, however the output still empty. It´s weird, I don´t understand why, because is the same test input that this post, any recommendation?

Comment: Another question, the `./script.pl data.dat` is necessary? or using `perl file.pl datafile.txt` it´s the same?

Comment: You are free to name script files as you like but it make some sense to name according performed by script task. Datafile can be named in any form which would make a sense to you for example `dna_sample1.dat`, `dna_sample2.dat`, ... , `dna_sample###.dat` or `client_1.dat`, `client_2.dat`, ..., `client_###.dat`. An extension `.dat` added to signify that it is data, but you can assign any extention which would make sense to you -- for example `.dna`, `.gen(ome)`.

Comment: If you are in Linux/UNIX/Mac OSX/BSD system then use [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20shebang%20is,bang%2C%20or%20hash%2Dpling.)  and make the script executable `chmod +x script.pl`. It would allow you run script without specifying `perl` in front of the script -- OS will look at __shebang__ string in the script and will figure out that it should be run with `perl`. Small trick which makes less typing.

Comment: I got it, perfect. Thank you for your specifications. However, I´m still having the empty output when I run the script. For more detail, here is the link with the test_file (input) and real data with more lines (input), your script is here too. Could you run the script with this data to check if works for you? Because not to me [link]https://github.com/MauriAndresMU1313/Example_NetNGlyc/tree/main @PolarBear

Comment: Please see my note at very end of my reply -- it explains why you do not getting any result.

Comment: I got it, I going to try your specification, anyway: Thank you for the script and your help!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232065/discussion-between-mauri1313-and-polar-bear).